# IMemoryCache get return null after setting a value asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to use IMemoryCache service in my ASP.NET CORE 2.2 Web API app. I have added the service in ConfigureServices function in startup ( .AddMemoryCache()).
Before starting to use it, I decided to test and see if I can successfully set a value and retrieve it by using the service.
Unfortunately, whenever I set a value then try to retrieve it, the API response return 204 No Content found.
What have I done wrong, please help.
Thank you.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Then in my TestController

```
namespace JwtTut.Controllers
{
    [Route("api")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
    private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;
    private IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public TestController(ILogger<TestController> logger, ApplicationDbContext context,
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        IIdentityService identityService, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
        _identityService = identityService;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    [HttpGet("user-claims")]
    public IActionResult GetUserClaims()
    {
        var randomList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            randomList.Add($"{i}");
        }

        _memoryCache.Set("randomLIst", randomList);
        var fromCache = _memoryCache.Get<string>("randomList");

        return Ok(fromCache);
    }
}
```

}

I am using the api/user-claims to test the IMemoryCache service

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I have added my code, please have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at below two lines. The key (randomLIst) you have used to set the cache is different from the key (randomList) you are using to get the cache:

```
_memoryCache.Set("randomLIst", randomList);
var fromCache = _memoryCache.Get<string>("randomList");
```

Correction made:

```
_memoryCache.Set("randomList", randomList);
var fromCache = _memoryCache.Get<string>("randomList");
```

I'll suggest you to make a separate utility class for Cache Keys to avoid typographical errors.

Comment: Silly me! Thanks broh!